# Count number of times a record has been edited

Tags: custom-field

Let consider an object which has a field called edit_counting. We knew that for every record, we have a button called EDIT to update the record. First time I edited and save the record. Now the value of Edit_counting is should be 1. Like this How many times I edit the record, that many times the field value needs to get updated automatically. Please can anyone help me in this? 
Note: Field may be any data type.

Thanks in advance

Kumaran

Comment: You can do it for particular fields, using a workflow.
if you want to track changes, better design is to use History Tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom number field and set the default value to zero.  Then create a WFR.  Your formula would look something like this

```
OR(
ISCHANGED(Field1__c),
ISCHANGED(Field2__c),
ISCHANGED(Field3__c),
ISCHANGED(Field4__c),
ISCHANGED(Field5__c),
ISCHANGED(Field6__c),
ISCHANGED(Field7__c),
ISCHANGED(Field8__c),
ISCHANGED(Field9__c),
ISCHANGED(Field10__c)
)
```

Then you create an immediate action of a field update.  And your formula for the field update would be

```
Your_Custom_Number_Field__c + 1
```

This increases your number field by 1 each time your custom field is changed to a non null value.

You can add other fields in the criteria using OR condition

Comment: Hi CODEPirate, I wanna Your_Custom_Number_Field__c is not editable by anyone. I made this field read-only by using page layout. Even though it is editable. How to made it non editable?????

Comment: Looks like you are on system administrator profile. Admins have the permission to edit fields which are made read-only on pagelayouts

Answer (score 0):

To track the changes made in field create workflow as follows :

- Create a Number field for Edit_counting
- Create a workflow that fires whenever there is a edit made by using this formula `ISCHANGED(tracking_field)`
- Do a field update on number field as `<Edit_counting> + 1 .`